# Access NFS files from Docker

Tags: docker

On Docker Host

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx ~]$ sudo mount serverfile-1.mylab.mydomain.com:/myapp /myapp/fsdata

[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx ~]$ ls -l /myapp/fsdata/resources
total 68

[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx ~]$ docker run -it --rm -v /myapp/fsdata:/myapp ubuntu bash
```

On Container

```
root@80f05ddfe73c:/# ls -l /myapp/resources
total 0
```

How is that possible? Why I can see mounted files on Host but not on Container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, after hours of solving the puzzle - solution was just to restart Docker service before running a Container

> > sudo service docker restart